# How to write a custom function to judge whether a bivariate function is differentiable at a certain point?

Tags: function-construction, calculus-and-analysis

We know that the necessary and sufficient conditions for a multivariate function to be differentiable at a certain point are [complicated](http://www.cnki.com.cn/Article/CJFDTotal-JGSS200904002.htm):

[image]

> Suppose the function $z = f (x_ 1, x_ 2, ..., x_n) $ is defined in the neighborhood $U$ of the point $P_ 0 (x_ {10}, x_ {20}, ..., x_{n0}) $. Then the sufficient and necessary conditions for the function $z = f (x_ 1, x_ 2, ..., x_n) $ to be differentiable at the point $P_ 0 (x_ {10}, x_ {20}, ..., x_{n0}) $ are:
>
> The n first-order partial derivatives of the function  $z = f (x_ 1, x_ 2, ..., x_n) $  at the point $P_ 0 (x_ {10}, x_ {20}, ..., x_{n0}) $ all exist, and $$f (x_ 1, x_ 2, ..., x_n) - f (x_ {10}, x_ 2, ..., x_n) - 
>   f (x_ 1, x_ {20}, ..., x_n) - ... -f (x_ 1, x_ 2, ..., x_{n0}) + 
>   f (x_ {10}, x_ {20}, ..., x_{n0}) = o (\rho) $$
>
> where $(x_ 1, x_ 2, ..., x_n) \in U$, $\rho = \sqrt{(x_ 1 - x_ {10})^2 + (x_ 2 - x_ {20})^2 + ... + (x_n - 
>     x_ {n0})^2}$.

I already know that the following bivariate function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at point $(0,0)$, but its two first-order partial derivatives are not continuous at $(0,0)$:

$$f(x, y)=\begin{cases}(x^2 + y^2) \sin(\frac{1}{(x^2 + y^2)}), &(x, y)  \neq (0, 0) \cr  0 , &(x, y)=(0, 0)\end{cases}
$$

```
f[x_, y_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(x^2 + y^2) Sin[1/(x^2 + y^2)], x^2 + y^2 != 0}}, 0]
D[f[x, y], x] /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}
D[f[x, y], y] /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}
Limit[(f[x, y] - f[x, 0] - f[0, y] + f[0, 0])/Sqrt[
 x^2 + y^2], {x, y} -> {0, 0}]
```

**I want to write a custom function to judge whether a bivariate function is differentiable at a certain point. How should I write this function?**

For example, through this custom function, we'll be able to judge that the following bivariate function is NOT differentiable at $(0,0)$:

$$f(x, y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}, &(x, y)  \neq (0, 0) \cr 0, &(x, y)=(0, 0)\end{cases}
$$

The following bivariate function should be differentiable at point $(0,0)$:

$$f(x, y)=\begin{cases}(x^2 + y^3) \sin(\frac{1}{(x^2 + y^2)}), &(x, y)  \neq (0, 0) \cr 0, &(x, y)=(0, 0)\end{cases}
$$

```
f[x_, y_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(x^2 + y^3) Sin[1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], x^2 + y^2 != 0}}, 0]
Limit[(f[0 + Δx, 
   0 + Δy] - (D[f[x, y], x] /. {x -> 0, 
      y -> 0}) Δx - (D[f[x, y], y] /. {x -> 0, 
      y -> 0}) Δy)/Sqrt[Δx^2 + Δy^2], {Δx, Δy} -> {0, 0}]
```

**Correction information:**

*After careful examination, I found that the theorem in the paper was wrongly written due to the author's negligence. The correct form is as follows:*

$$f (x_ 1, x_ 2, ..., x_n) - f (x_ 1, x_ {20}, ..., x_ {n0}) - 
f (x_ {10}, x_ 2, ..., x_ {n0}) - ... - 
  f (x_ {10}, x_ {20}, ..., x_n) + (n - 1) f (x_ {10}, x_ {20}, ..., 
x_ {n0}) = o (\rho)$$

*where n is the number of variables of this multivariate function.*

Comment: It's actually not difficult, but takes some effort. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @SneezeFor16Min I want to know how you would write this universal decision function? Thank you.

Comment: I would call this a *bivariate* function. When I read binary I thought of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ and was wondering how you define differentiability.

Comment: @Natas Thx, I have updated the question.

Comment: Please check if the theorem is correct. $f(x,y,z)=|x|+|y|+|z|$ is differentiable at $(1,2,3)$, but the limit according to this theorem is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quite interested in this problem so took some efforts to write it. Since you've given the conditions for multivariate functions, I wrote a more general version than just for bivariate functions.

```
ClearAll[differentiableAtQ];
differentiableAtQ[
  f_, p_?VectorQ, vars_?VectorQ, dom_ : Reals
  ] := With[{n = Length[vars], dimP = Length[p]},
  If[n < 1 || n != dimP, Return[]];
  If[n > 1,
   With[{pd = D[f, #] & /@ vars},
    With[{pdValues = ((Evaluate[vars] \[Function] #) @@ p) & /@ pd},
     (* All partial derivatives exist *)
     AllTrue[pdValues, NumericQ] &&
      With[{$f = Evaluate[vars] \[Function] Evaluate[f]},
       (* All partial derivatives are continuous *)
       AllTrue[{pd, pdValues}\[Transpose],
         Apply[Limit[#1, vars -> p] === #2 &]
         ] || Switch[ (* Taking limit *)
         Limit[FullSimplify[
           (If[MemberQ[#, _Piecewise, \[Infinity]],
               # // PiecewiseExpand, #] &)[
            (* Edit for correction (n-1) *)
            ($f @@ vars + (n - 1) $f @@ p
               - Total[
                $f @@@ (ConstantArray[vars, n]
                   + DiagonalMatrix[p - vars])
                ])/Norm[vars - p]],
           And @@ Thread[vars != p]
            && vars \[Element] dom],
          vars -> p],
         0, True,
         Indeterminate, False,
         _DirectedInfinity, False,
         _, Indeterminate
         ]
       ]]],
   D[f, vars] /. vars[[1]] -> p[[1]] // NumericQ
   ]]
```

## Test

Examples in your question:

```
differentiableAtQ[
 Piecewise[
  {{0, {x, y} == {0, 0}}},
  (x^2 + y^2) Sin[1/(x^2 + y^2)]
  ], {0, 0}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
differentiableAtQ[
 Piecewise[
  {{0,
      {x, y} == {0, 0}}},
  (x^2 y)/(x^4 + y^2)],
 {0, 0}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Example in comment:

```
differentiableAtQ[
 Piecewise[
  {{(x^2 + y^3) Sin[1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], x^2 + y^2 != 0}},
  0],
 {0, 0}, {x, y}
 ]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
differentiableAtQ[
 Piecewise[{
   {0,
       {x, y} == {0, 0}},
   {(x^2 + y^2),
       y < 0}},
  (x^2 + y^2) Sin[1/(x^2 + y^2)]],
 {0, 0}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> Indeterminate
> ```

Univariate:

```
differentiableAtQ[RealAbs[x], {0}, {x}]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
differentiableAtQ[RealAbs[x], {1}, {x}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Bivariate:

```
differentiableAtQ[RealAbs[x] + RealAbs[y], {1, 1}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
differentiableAtQ[RealAbs[x] + RealAbs[y], {0, 1}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Trivariate:

```
differentiableAtQ[
 RealAbs[x] + RealAbs[y] + RealAbs[z],
 {1, 1, 1}, {x, y, z}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
differentiableAtQ[
 RealAbs[x] + RealAbs[y] + RealAbs[z],
 {1, 1, 0}, {x, y, z}]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Comment: I found that your custom function should be wrong in judging whether this binary function is differentiable at {0,0}: `f[x_, y_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(x^2 + y^3) Sin[1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], x^2 + y^2 != 0}}, 0]`

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes: Oh, I'll check it later.

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes: I've updated, and please try more examples.

Comment: Hi, it seems to fail on this: `Piecewise[{{0, {x, y} == {0, 0}}, {(x^2 + y^2), y < 0}}, (x^2 + y^2) Sin[1/(x^2 + y^2)]]` at `{0, 0}`, if you're applying the $(F - dF.\Delta x)/\Vert \Delta x \Vert \rightarrow 0$ definition.

Comment: @MichaelE2: The problem is taking limit on a piecewise function. I'll mark it as `Indeterminate`.

Comment: @MichaelE2: It would be better if you can post formula or *Mathematica* code (like attach it to my answer) to show it's (non-)differentiable so that improvement may be made.

Comment: OK, done.  See my answer.  `Limit` was a bit unpredictable when `Piecewise` was involved, so I hope I didn't overlook something.

Comment: @SneezeFor16Min  I'm sorry. I found that the theorem in the paper is not correct. I've corrected the errors, but I'm not sure whether my corrections are completely correct.

Comment: PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes: I've modified my code according to your correction. Yesterday I used an alternative way, the continuity of partial derivatives, to determine the differentiability of $|x|+|y|+|z|$, but it's still not enough to determine the example given by @MichaelE2.

Answer (score 3):

If `Limit` were infallible, then the following would do it:

```
differentiableQ[f_, spec : (v_ -> v0_)] := With[{jac = D[f, {v}]},
   Module[{f0, jac0},
     {f0, jac0} = {f, jac} /. Thread[spec];
     VectorQ[Flatten@{f0, jac0}, NumericQ] &&
       Limit[(f - f0 - jac0.(v - v0))/Sqrt@Total[(v - v0)^2], spec] === 0 
     ] /; VectorQ[jac]
   ];
```

But `Limit` is not infallible, so it might pay to work around its limitations.  In particular, it is not yet robust on `Piecewise` functions, which is of particular interest to the OP.

We can add a step to the above to try harder when `Limit` fails and a `Piecewise` function is present.

```
ClearAll[differentiableQ, dLimit];
differentiableQ[f_, spec : (v_ -> v0_)] := With[{jac = D[f, {v}]},
   Module[{f0, jac0, res},
     {f0, jac0} = {f, jac} /. Thread[spec];
     If[VectorQ[Flatten@{f0, jac0}, NumericQ],
      res = 
       Limit[(f - f0 - jac0.(v - v0))/Sqrt@Total[(v - v0)^2], spec] /.
          HoldPattern[Limit[df_, s_]] /; ! FreeQ[df, Piecewise] :> 
         With[{L = dLimit[df, s]}, L /; FreeQ[L, dLimit]];
      res = FreeQ[res, Indeterminate] &&
         And @@ Thread[Flatten@{res} == 0],
      res = False
      ]] /; VectorQ[jac]
   ];
dLimit[df_, spec_] := Module[{f0, jac0, pcs = {}, z, res},
   pcs = Replace[
     (* Solve[.., Reals] separates PW fn *)
     z /. Solve[z == df, z, Reals],
     {ConditionalExpression[y_, c_] :> {y, c}, y_ :> {y, True}},
     1];
   If[ListQ[pcs],
    res = (Limit[Piecewise[{#}], spec] /.
         HoldPattern[Limit[Piecewise[{{y_, _}}, 0], s_]] :> 
          With[{L = Limit[y, s]}, L /; FreeQ[L, Limit]]
        & /@ pcs)
    ];
   res /; ListQ[pcs]
   ];
```

Examples:

```
differentiableQ[
 Piecewise[{{(x^2 + y^2) Sin[1/(x^2 + y^2)], {x, y} != {0, 0}}}],
  {x, y} -> {0, 0}]
```

> ```
> (*  True  *)
> ```

```
differentiableQ[
 Piecewise[{{0, {x, y} == {0, 0}},
   {(x^2 + y^2), y < 0}}, (x^2 + y^2) Sin[1/(x^2 + y^2)]],
  {x, y} -> {0, 0}]
```

> ```
> (*  True  *)
> ```

Comment: What definition do you use? Because I see the `jac0.(v - v0)`. *BTW, I like your `spec : (v_ -> v0_)` -- I should've written like this!*

Comment: @Michael E2 Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @SneezeFor16Min The limit of $[\,f(x) - (\,f(x_0) + \nabla f(x_0)\cdot(x-x_0)\,)\,]/\Vert x-x_0 \Vert$ should be zero at $x\rightarrow x_0$.  I didn't understand the (original) statement in the quoted theorem at first, as it seemed ("We know...") a botched attempt at the usual definition and was in Chinese. So I took a stab at the question in the title. One might be able to apply the `dLimit` idea to limits of piecewise functions to the desired approach in the theorem. Conceivably `PiecewiseExpand` might be needed to help `Solve`.

Comment: I'd also add that the advantage of the theorem seems to be, ***if*** you can assume the partial derivatives exist, then the criterion does not require computing them.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's great! Maybe this definition is better to operate on.

Comment: Unfortunately, `differentiableQ[
 Piecewise[{{(x^2 + y^2) Sin[1/(x^2 + y^2)^3], {x, y} != {0, 
      0}}}], {x, y} -> {0, 0}]` performs `True` which is wrong in view of `D[r^2*Sin[r^-6], r]`.

Comment: @user64494 Your example is differentiable at the origin, so `True` is the result I would want.  `Piecewise[{{r^2*Sin[r^-6], r != 0}}]` is also differentiable at `r = 0`: apply the limit definition.  `D[r^2*Sin[r^-6], r]` is valid only for `r != 0` and does not apply to the example.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Your answer is great, but when dealing with these examples of unit functions, your results are not correct:`differentiableQ[RealAbs[x] Sin[RealAbs[x]], {x} -> {0}] differentiableQ[Cos[Sqrt[RealAbs[x]]], {x} -> {0}]` or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/227875/how-to-judge-whether-a-single-variable-function-is-differentiable-at-a-certain-p).

Comment: @Ordinaryusers68 It fails on the first because the built-in `D` fails on it. Note sure if that's worth addressing. I guess I could throw in a `PiecewiseExpand`: `differentiableQ[
 PiecewiseExpand[RealAbs[x] Sin[RealAbs[x]]], {x} -> {0}]`.  I get the correct answer for `Cos[Sqrt[RealAbs[x]]]`, i.e., `False`. Did you get `True`?

Comment: Note in my previous comment, I said, "**if** you can assume the partial derivatives exist": I would add, if you can assume `D[]` computes them correctly.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you very much. After adding `PiecewiseExpand`, I did get the right result.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael E2 said, it is not always reliable to use the `Limit` function to find the limit. In addition, I found that the definition in the paper should be wrong. For example, the result of the following example is not correct:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := (RealAbs[x] + RealAbs[y] + RealAbs[z])
Limit[(f[x, y, z] - f[1, y, z] - f[x, 2, z] - f[x, y, 3] + 
  f[1, 2, 3])/Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 + (z - 3)^2], {x, y, 
   z} -> {1, 2, 3}]
(*According to the theorem mentioned in the question description*)
(*-∞*)
Limit[(f[0 + Δx, 0 + Δy, 
   0 + Δz] - Δx - Δy - \
Δz)/Sqrt[Δx^2 + Δy^2 + Δz^2], {Δx, Δy, \
Δz} -> {1, 2, 
   3}](*According to the differentiable definition of multivariate \
function*)
(*0*)
```

We can find that the results of the two methods are not the same, but in the following simplified example, the results are consistent:

```
g[x_, y_] := (RealAbs[x] + RealAbs[y])
Limit[(g[x, y] - g[1, y] - g[x, 2] + 
  g[1, 2])/Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2], {x, y} -> {1, 2}]
(*According to the theorem mentioned in the question description*)
(*0*)
Limit[(g[0 + Δx, 
   0 + Δy] - Δx - Δy)/Sqrt[\
Δx^2 + Δy^2], {Δx, Δy} -> {1, 2}]
(*According to the differentiable definition of multivariate function*)

(*0*)
```

After careful examination, I found that some details of the theorem in the paper are wrong, which should be written in the following way:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := (RealAbs[x] + RealAbs[y] + RealAbs[z])
Limit[1/(Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 + (z - 3)^2])*((f[x, y, z] - 
     f[1, 2, 3])(*Δz*)- ((f[x, 2, 3] - 
       f[1, 2, 3])(*fx*Δx*)+ (f[1, y, 3] - 
       f[1, 2, 3])(*fy*Δy*)+ (f[1, 2, z] - 
       f[1, 2, 3])(*fz*Δz*))), {x, y, z} -> {1, 2, 3}]
```

It can also be abbreviated to the following format:

```
Limit[(f[x, y, z] - f[x, 2, 3] - f[1, y, 3] - f[1, 2, z] + 
  (3-1)* f[1, 2, 3])/Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 + (z - 3)^2], {x, y, 
   z} -> {1, 2, 3}]
```

The result of this limit is 0, which is consistent with the result of derivation by definition, that is, the function $f(x)=\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert+\lvert z\rvert$ is differentiable at point {1,2,3}.