# Limit of multivariate piecewise function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

Let's say we have a multivariate piecewise function

```
f[x1_,x2_]:=Piecewise[{{Sin[x1]/x1,x1>x2},{Sin[x2]/x2,x1<=x2}}]
```

Now we want to determine the limit in f(0,0) with the Limit function.
From the wolfram doc I can see two possible ways to do so.

```
Limit[f[x1,x2], {x1,x2}->{0,0}]
Limit[f[x,x], x->0]
```

While the first expression does not evaluate the limit, the second one gives the expected result 1.

Why does the first expression not work?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225100/4999 -- Multivariate limits do not seem to be robust with respect to `Piecewise` functions yet. Possibly related is that there does not appear to be a way to limit the domain in a multivariate limit (the way you can with `Direction`). This would be needed to find limits of piecewise functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that `Limit` can have trouble if `(x, y} -> {a, b}` where `{a, b}` is not an interior point of the domain.  For instance, I would say the limit here is well-defined since `{0, 0}` is a limit point of the domain and that the limit is `1`:

```
Limit[ConditionalExpression[Sin[x1]/x1, x1 > x2], {x1, x2} -> {0, 0}]
```

> ```
> (*  Indeterminate  *)
> ```

`Limit` can handle some piecewise functions:

```
Limit[
 Piecewise[{
  { Sin[1/x1] / x1, x1 > x2}, (* <-- N.B. *)
  {Sin[x2]/x2, x1 <= x2}}],
 {x1, x2} -> {0, 0}]

(*  Indeterminate  *)
```

So it seems to be a question of robustness.

An alternative when `Limit` fails is to try to find the limit of each of the separate pieces without the restriction on the domain of the piece.  If they each exist and are equal, we can say the limit is the limit of the pieces.  If some exist and are not all equal, then the limit does not exist. Otherwise, I think we can't be sure.  The following is adapted from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225100/4999) of mine.

```
ClearAll[pwLimit];
pwLimit::DNE = 
  "The limit of at least one of the pieces does not exist as ``.";
pwLimit::nopcs = "Could not solve for the pieces.";
pwLimit[f_, spec_, opts : OptionsPattern[Limit]] := 
  Module[{f0, jac0, pcs = {}, z, res}, 
   pcs = Replace[ (* Solve[..,Reals] separates PW fn *)
     z /. Solve[z == f, z, Reals],
     {ConditionalExpression[y_, _] :> y},
     1];
   If[ListQ[pcs],
    res = Limit[#, spec, opts] & /@ pcs,
    Message[pwLimit::nopcs];
    res = $Failed];
   res = Replace[res, {
      uneval_ /;  (* Limit did not find limit *)
         ! FreeQ[uneval, Limit] :>
       $Failed,
      lim_ /;  (* all limits equal *)
         Equal @@ lim :> 
       First@lim,
      lim_ /;  (* limits exist/infinite but different *)
         VectorQ[lim, 
          NumericQ[#] || MatchQ[#, Infinity | -Infinity | ComplexInfinity] &
          ] :> 
       Indeterminate,
      lim_ :>  (* at least two limits exist and differ *)
        With[{nums = 
          Cases[lim, _?NumericQ | Infinity | -Infinity | ComplexInfinity]},
         Indeterminate /; Length@Union[nums, SameTest -> Equal] > 1
         ],
      i_ /;  (* limit(s) DNE on whole domain but might on piece *)
         ! FreeQ[i, Indeterminate] :> (
       Message[pwLimit::DNE, spec]
       $Failed)
      }];
   res /; FreeQ[res, $Failed]];
```

It is called like `Limit`.  It might make sense to call it after `Limit` fails:

```
Limit[
  Piecewise[{{Sin[x1]/x1, x1 > x2}, {Sin[x2]/x2, x1 <= x2}}],
  {x1, x2} -> {0, 0}] /.
 Limit -> pwLimit

(*  1  *)
```

If you'd prefer that a failed call stay as `Limit[..]` instead of `pwLimit[..]]`, then the following will make the replacement only if `pwLimit` is successful.

```
Limit[
  Piecewise[{{Sin[x1]/x1, x1 > x2}, {Sin[x2]/x2, x1 <= x2}}],
  {x1, x2} -> {0, 0}] /. 
 HoldPattern[Limit[args__]] :> 
  With[{res = pwLimit[args]}, res /; FreeQ[res, pwLimit]]

(*  1  *)
```

Comment: Probably don't need third case (condition `VectorQ[..]`) as it would handled by the fourth case.

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks Michael!