# How to judge whether a single-variable function is differentiable at a certain point

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

[Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225100/42417) solves the problem of differentiability of multivariate functions.

```
ClearAll[differentiableQ, dLimit];
differentiableQ[f_, spec : (v_ -> v0_)] := With[{jac = D[f, {v}]},
   Module[{f0, jac0, res},
     {f0, jac0} = {f, jac} /. Thread[spec];
     If[VectorQ[Flatten@{f0, jac0}, NumericQ],
      res = 
       Limit[(f - f0 - jac0.(v - v0))/Sqrt@Total[(v - v0)^2], spec] /.
          HoldPattern[Limit[df_, s_]] /; ! FreeQ[df, Piecewise] :> 
         With[{L = dLimit[df, s]}, L /; FreeQ[L, dLimit]];
      res = FreeQ[res, Indeterminate] &&
         And @@ Thread[Flatten@{res} == 0],
      res = False
      ]] /; VectorQ[jac]
   ];
dLimit[df_, spec_] := Module[{f0, jac0, pcs = {}, z, res},
   pcs = Replace[
     (* Solve[.., Reals] separates PW fn *)
     z /. Solve[z == df, z, Reals],
     {ConditionalExpression[y_, c_] :> {y, c}, y_ :> {y, True}},
     1];
   If[ListQ[pcs],
    res = (Limit[Piecewise[{#}], spec] /.
         HoldPattern[Limit[Piecewise[{{y_, _}}, 0], s_]] :> 
          With[{L = Limit[y, s]}, L /; FreeQ[L, Limit]]
        & /@ pcs)
    ];
   res /; ListQ[pcs]
   ];
```

But when I applied it to the following univariate function problem, I encountered a problem:

$$\begin{array}{c}
(A)\;  f(x)=|x| \sin |x| \qquad 
(B)\;  f(x)=|x| \sin \sqrt{|x|} \\
(C)\;  f(x)=\cos |x| \qquad 
(D)\;  f(x)=\cos \sqrt{|x|} 
\end{array}$$

```
differentiableQ[RealAbs[x] Sin[RealAbs[x]], {x} -> {0}]
differentiableQ[RealAbs[x] Sin[Sqrt[RealAbs[x]]], {x} -> {0}]
differentiableQ[Cos[RealAbs[x]], {x} -> {0}]
differentiableQ[Cos[Sqrt[RealAbs[x]]], {x} -> {0}]
```

[image]

The three functions A, B and C are differentiable at the point `x=0`, so the judgment result of the function `differentiableQ` is wrong.

How can I write a general user-defined function that can judge whether piecewise function, univariate function and multivariable function are differentiable at a certain point?

**Mathematical analysis process:**

$A: \quad f_{+}^{\prime}(0)=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{|x| \sin |x|}{x}=0, f_{-}^{\prime}(0)=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{-}} \frac{-x \sin (-x)}{x}=0, \text { So } f^{\prime}(0)=0$

$B: \quad f_{+}^{\prime}(0)=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{x \sin (\sqrt{x})}{x}=0, f_{-}^{\prime}(0)=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{-}} \frac{-x \sin (\sqrt{-x})}{x}=0, \Rightarrow  f^{\prime}(0)=0$

$C: f_{+}^{\prime}(0)=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\cos x-1}{x}=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{-\frac{1}{2} x^{2}}{x}=0, f_{-}^{\prime}(0)=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{-}} \frac{\cos (-x)-1}{x}=0, \Rightarrow  f^{\prime}(0)=0$

$D: \begin{aligned}
 f_{+}^{\prime}(0)=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\cos \sqrt{x}-1}{x}=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{-\frac{1}{2} x}{x}=-\frac{1}{2}\\
 f_{-}^{\prime}(0)=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{-}} \frac{\cos (\sqrt{-x})-1}{x}=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0^{-}} \frac{-\frac{1}{2}(-x)}{x}=\frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}$

Comment: In these cases, a simple `Limit[D[f[x],x],x->0]` already shows whether the function is differentiable - the issue with the "more robust" solution is that inserting `0` into the Jacobian does not work without taking the limit. But since the whole point of this function is to work around the shortcomings on `Limit`, I'm not sure how to best fix this

Comment: @LukasLang `Limit[D[f[x],x],x->0]` will show whether the derivative is continuous. It fails to show `Piecewise[{{x^2 Sin[1/x], x != 0}}]` is differentiable at `x = 0`.

Comment: As I mentioned elsewhere, `differentiableQ` assumes `D[]` can compute the Jacobian strictly correctly, which it fails to do in these cases.  Theoretically, you could replace `D[]` in `jac = D[f, {v}]` by the limits for each partial derivative.  Of course, `Limit` is not completely reliable, either.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for pointing that out, you're of course correct. When I saw that that method produces the "correct" result (i.e. `Indeterminate` for only the last example), I didn't think twice about the actual meaning of that limit